# Autoit dead loop problem

Tags: deadlock, ssms, autoit

In SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), you have to middle-click the tab or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current editor tab. I want to use `Autoit` to make a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> do the same thing. But I have problem with it. The following is the code. What I thought is, when the user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, check if the user is in `SSMS`, if so, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current tab, if not, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to let it go as normal. But the point is, if you send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, it will be captured again by Autoit, so dead loop occurs. I can't find a way to solve this problem. Anyone can help me with it?

Thanks.

```
HotKeySet("^w", "close_ssms_editor")

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

; using Ctrl + w to close
; * editors in SSMS
; * editors in SSMS through Royal TS
Func close_ssms_editor()
    $window_class_name = get_window_class_name(WinGetHandle(""))
    If $window_class_name = "wndclass_desked_gsk" or $window_class_name = "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.218f99c" Then
        Send("^{F4}")
    Else
        Send("^w")
    EndIf
EndFunc


Func get_window_class_name($nCtrl)
    If Not IsHWnd($nCtrl) then $nCtrl = HWnd($nCtrl)
    Local $struct = DllStructCreate("char[128]"),$classname = 0
    $ret = DllCall("user32.dll","int","GetClassName","hwnd",$nCtrl,"ptr",DllStructGetPtr($struct),"int",DllStructGetSize($struct))
    If IsArray($ret) Then
        $classname = DllStructGetData($struct,1)
        While (StringIsDigit(StringRight($classname,1)))
            $classname = StringTrimRight($classname,1)
        WEnd
    EndIf
    $struct =0 
    Return $classname
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
; using Ctrl + w to close
; * editor in SSMS
; * editor in SSMS through Royal TS
Func close_ssms_editor()
    $window_class_name = get_window_class_name(WinGetHandle(""))
    If $window_class_name = "wndclass_desked_gsk" or $window_class_name = "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.218f99c" Then
        Send("^{F4}")
    Else
        HotKeySet("^w")
        Send("^w")
        HotKeySet("^w", "close_ssms_editor")
    EndIf
EndFunc
```